# Interpretation T-test

Tags: python, t-test, pandas

First of all, I guess I should start my question exposing what is the data about and how it looks right now, I have the following pd.Series object. They are basically the daily conversion of a few days before and after the insertion of a new service inside a bot.

```
conversions_pre_flux = pd.Series({datetime.date(2022, 10, 1): 9.333333333333334,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 2): 11.46031746031746,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 3): 10.382978723404255,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 4): 11.195219123505977,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 5): 8.225296442687746,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 6): 9.313390313390313,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 7): 8.108187134502923,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 8): 9.85820895522388,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 9): 7.580487804878048})

conversions_after_flux = pd.Series({datetime.date(2022, 10, 15): 9.051282051282051,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 16): 8.909090909090908,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 17): 8.32258064516129,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 18): 9.93732970027248,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 19): 9.225961538461538,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 20): 9.49476439790576,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 21): 8.537396121883656,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 22): 7.755813953488372,
 datetime.date(2022, 10, 23): 10.11111111111111})
```

I have been utilizing the libray pinguino

```
import pingouin as pg
```

[image]

My question is with the given information, what would be your formulated hypothesis? Mine is currently accepting the null hypothesis and saying that there is no difference between the two groups means. Is that interpretation correct, is the type of daily conversion the correct way to approach this issue? The groups utilize the same bot, but they are guaranteed to be different users, in this case they are independent correct? Also what else could be concluded from the other give infos given by pingouin?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/8983c088d9916ea82772857a1d48bfdb) is a Python gist plotting your data over time.

Comment: The `power=0.130849` tells us this test didn't have much [statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_test), suggesting you were not likely to have detected a difference in population mean if there was one.

Comment: Humm i see, so is kinda of a way of validating whether or not I am correctly not rejecting the null hypothesis

Comment: Does that mean, I made a type 1 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is first, we never *accept* the null only *fail to reject*.  Second, a hypothesis comes prior to a test.

From the results of the test, it would seem that the data are consistent with a true difference of 0 (at least if we assume a 5% significance level).  But that doesn't tell the whole story, and it would be very difficult to believe this without additional information (because for instance there could be a confounding factor not accounted for).

So, can you tell us how these data were collected?

Comment: I can actually, this is a given percent made by the amount of users who entered the bot compared to the amount, who ordered something. So basically the conversion rate of that given day. In this case the data is gathered straight from the bot itself.

Comment: I took a glance at your answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462293/how-to-compare-conversion-rates-in-an-ab-test, guess I could try doing as the given step by step

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 That sounds like a good place to start.